# How can I set wget to download only newer file in a specific url?

Tags: bash, scripts, downloads, wget

How do I get wget to download only newest file version in a url?

Sample url:
https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge/pool/main/m/microsoft-edge-stable/

As you can see, there are multiple versions of Edge installer file.

Comment: Specifically bash? seems not the most fit language for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the whole URL.

So you need to use:

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge/pool/main/m/microsoft-edge-stable/microsoft-edge-stable_95.0.1020.40-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: thanks,but i mean automatically detect and download newest file, not manual! i want create a bash script that included this job,